# Dart - Nested then never completes

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I would like to have nested then callbacks as below:
**somemethod1** and **somemethod2** inside both functions return future.

```
Future<T> **somefunctionA**() => ...somemethod1().then((value) => return T);

Future<T> **somefunctionB**() => ...somemethod2.then((value) async { 
    await **somefunctionA**();
    /// then post processing...
}).then((value) => do something);
```

I have implemented this, but the nested then callback inside somefunctionA never completes.
Instead, the outer then callback to somefunctionB gets called once the future inside somefunctionA completes.

How do I make this work in such a way that the inner then callbacks must be completed before the outer then executes?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Please provide a reproducible example that demonstrates the problem. 2. It makes little sense to mix `.then()` and `async`/`await`.  Using `async`/`await` is simpler and easier to read; just use that.

Comment: @jamesdlin:  I updated the question with an example...

Comment: add some `print()`s to check if `Future.then` methods are really not called, like this for example: `void main() {
print('foo');
a().then((b) => print('outer then $b'));
print('bar');
}

Future<bool> a() async {
return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => 10)
.then((i) {
print('inner then $i');
return i == 10;
});
}` - the above code snippet show: `foo<CRLF>
bar<CRLF>
inner then 10<CRLF>
outer then true` on the logs

Comment: @AmalenduPandit A reproducible example is something that other people can easily run to reproduce your problem.  The code you've posted is not a complete program.   Ideally you also would create a [*minimal* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by removing code that isn't necessary for the reproduction.  I don't know if it's related to your problem, but one of your callbacks does `return insertUserCollection(...)` along one code path but returns nothing along the other.

Comment: I checked today and the callback worked. The inner then callback executed perfectly and the control returned to the outer callback. Thanks guys for the help. Much appreciated.